# django: Show count of entries with specific field

Tags: django

I have the following model

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    region = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

What is the best way to get total amount of shops in each location. E.g. I want to get something like

```
{'us': 10, 'uk': 15, ...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset

So perhaps something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
shops = Shop.objects.all().values('region').annotate(total=Count('region'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this worked for me

```
Shop.objects.all().values('region').annotate(total=Count('region'))
```